# How do I right-click-drag with a single button touchpad in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I have a laptop with Windows 10. It has a Macbook-style touchpad, where it is just one big button.  In the control panel, I can set right-click to tapping with two fingers.  However, if I want to right-click-drag, there seems to be no option.  Intuitively, I would expect that I could accomplish this by pressing down the touchpad with two fingers so that it clicks, and then dragging, but it doesn't work.
I need to right-click-drag in the Unity Editor, and there's no way to rebind it.

Comment: @Didier Regular drag-and-drop does work, but only with left click.  In Windows, if I right-click-drag-and-drop a file using a mouse, it gives me a "Copy here/Move here/Shortcut here" context window popup.  I can't seem to do that with a touchpad.

Comment: Is this why you want to do it with your right-click instead of left-click? https://www.brucebnews.com/2016/07/windows-tip-drag-and-drop-with-the-right-mouse-button/ EDIT: I can do that with my TouchPad on a Lenovo laptop, so I guess it could be a matter of installing the right driver for yours. What's the brand and model of your PC? Does it have a clickable touchpad?

Comment: Yes, that's the functionality I want.  I have a Razer Blade 15, it has a clickable touchpad.  I'll look around to see if maybe there's alternate drivers that I've missed.

Comment: If your touchpad works the way it does in older Macs, then it's a matter of how long you press before going from left-click (one short press) to right-click (one longer press).

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know is to use two hands. You position the cursor on your target with a single finger motion and then, click and hold along the right edge of the touch-pad and, with the other hand, do the drag.
Jerry